# SQlite delete all rows that has a specific string value

Tags: android, sqlite, delete-row

This code delete only single record in my Table, what i want to achieve is, delete all records that have a given string phone value. Im new to SQlite, a little help are much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

This code delete single Record sucessfully:

```
public void delSmsData(int id){
    String deleteQuery = "DELETE FROM "+TABLE_LO_SMSDATA+" WHERE _id="+id+"";
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.execSQL(deleteQuery); //delete single row by ID in a table
    db.execSQL("vacuum");
    db.close();
    Log.e("Debug", "Successful delete of message with id no. " + id);
}
```

I successfuly deleted all the records with this code. Thanks to those who helped.

```
public void delAllSmsByPhone(String phone){
    String deleteQuery = "DELETE FROM "+TABLE_LO_SMSDATA+" WHERE _phone='"+phone+"'";
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.execSQL(deleteQuery); 
    db.execSQL("vacuum");
    db.close();
}
```

This is my Table Structure:

```
String CREATE_LO_SMSDATA_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE "
            +TABLE_LO_SMSDATA+"("
            +KEY_ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
            +KEY_EMAIL+" TEXT,"
            +KEY_TARGETNAME+" TEXT,"
            +KEY_SMSTYPE+" TEXT,"
            +KEY_PHONE+" TEXT,"
            +KEY_CONTACTNAME+" TEXT,"
            +KEY_SMSBODY+" TEXT,"
            +KEY_DATE+" TEXT"+")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_LO_SMSDATA_TABLE);
```

Comment: what is your table structure? Is `_phone` the primary key?

Comment: @AdamForbis i updated the question.

Comment: `... WHERE _phone='"+phone+"'"`

Comment: can you add your data that need to be deleted but actually only one is deleted?cant image why one record is deleted and not the others IF they have the same column data. maybe they have space character at the end?

Comment: @Apostolos another update on post. thanks

Comment: Update doesn't answer @Apostolos question. What you have in your table before query, and what you have after query. Define "failed" too, please. Does app crashes, doesn't delete anything, deletes something another, etc.

Comment: @SergeyGlotov i updated the answer, i just want to delete those 5 records with a single call. What i mean is, after a single call of (delAllSmsByPhone) those 5 records should be deleted.

Comment: Any phones number get deleted after `delAllSmsByPhone` called ?

Comment: make a `select` query first and see if it returns all these records. if yes, `delete` SHOULD work

Comment: @SergeyGlotov thanks guys, i just compare an encrypted value with a readable value. It works perfectly now. Thank you very much for this ... WHERE _phone='"+phone+"'".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand you completely. Did you try to run the code?

> This code is not the right approach

It is absolutely right approach. `DELETE` can delete any count of rows not only one. It deletes all rows for which the `WHERE` clause is true.

Proof:

```
sqlite> .tables
sms
sqlite> .schema sms
CREATE TABLE `sms` (
    `_id`   INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    `_phone`    TEXT
);
sqlite> SELECT * FROM sms;
1|+79271234567
2|+79271234567
3|+79213983722
4|+79271234567
5|+78450738422
6|+79271234567
7|+77432739417
8|+74673627246
9|+79271234567
10|+79271234567
sqlite> DELETE FROM sms WHERE _phone='+79271234567';
sqlite> SELECT * FROM sms;
3|+79213983722
5|+78450738422
7|+77432739417
8|+74673627246
```

Comment: yes i forgot, sorry my phone is encrypted. Thanks for ... WHERE _phone='"+phone+"'" . This.